# “html agility pack” like solutions for C/Objective-c/iPhone

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, html-agility-pack, html-parser

I need a powerful HTML parser and manipulator for Objective-C/C, like HTML Agility Pack.

Can anyone tell me some optimal solution? One solution is libxml2, but it seams is not the best.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MacOS X, `NSXMLDocument` is a good solution (but you want iPhone).

Two packages that you should look at are: [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) and [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML).

See also [iPhone Development - XMLParser vs. libxml2 vs. TouchXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406811/iphone-development-xmlparser-vs-libxml2-vs-touchxml).

Comment: they're not optimized for iphone.

Comment: They work - I actually had some problems with TouchXML when I first tried it, and ended up using KissXML.