# How can I parse HTML?

Tags: iphone, html, xml

Let's say I have the following string:

```
NSString * str = "<a href="http://www.google.com"style="">
</br>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="" style="">Come on</a>hello world"
```

How can I parse out the value of the anchor tag--"Come on"?

Should I use HTMLNode.h and HTMLParser.h?  Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712213/html-agility-pack-like-solutions-for-c-objective-c-iphone

Answer (score 1):

If it is static, then you can use string manipulation to take out the substring out of the  tag

OR

If it is dynamic and html/xml code keeps changing then you can use NSXMLParser. Keep in mind that NSXMLParser should more preferably used only when data is in XML format.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi , Parth Bhatt.
thank you ,but  i want know how to use it !
you know ,it's static , i know use the tag '<html></html>', but the '<a herf="">' tag , so..

Comment: @FlyProgramer2Ball: May I know what difficulty you face in implementing NSXMLParser or the static method as I have mentioned?

Comment: `substringFromIndex:` and `substringToIndex:` method of NSString class  might be useful. For more info on this check out http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: thanks for your link.  The string values is static , looks like. but the value is return of the server client . so the string is dynamic , i can't use subStringToIndex .

Comment: @FlyProgramer2Ball: Here we can just guide you through. This is a community where we only encourage exchange of good ideas. Here we should not expect someone to give the whole code from a to z. Actually  for finding readymade codes and tutorials, you may search on Google. Here only a hint or a direction should be fine. And after searching on google if you dont find a proper tutorial then you may ask for one here on StackOverflow. Hope you get it. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, thank you @Parth Bhatt.
but you misunderstood me , i don't give code from a to z.