# IS touchXML a SAX parser?

Tags: iphone, xml

HEllo,

IS touchXML a SAX parser ? what about NSXMLparser ?Somebody  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following answer provided by Robbie Hanson (he pretty much sums it up already).

[iPhone Development - XMLParser vs. libxml2 vs. TouchXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406811/iphone-development-xmlparser-vs-libxml2-vs-touchxml/407925#407925)