# IPhone Development - Generate XML File

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch

Does anybody here know how to generate a XML file or string in the iPhone?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you just want to convert a simple dictionary/array to an XML format string then it's few lines of code. if you need something more sophisticated then I believe there are some ope-source libraries for that. If you want to convert your own object to a specific XML then I suppose you will have to build the XML string manually...

Comment: -1 Vague. Do you want *any* XML file, a generic XML writer, or a specific XML format?

Comment: In my question, I've said "a XML file or string ", it means any kind of XML file or string.

Comment: please note my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731773/store-data-to-xml-in-my-app/3731791#3731791)

Answer (score 1):

Try the open source [XML stream writer for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/xswi/):

- Written in Objective-C, a single .h. and .m file
- One @protocol for namespace support and one for without

Example:

```
// allocate serializer
XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

// start writing XML elements
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Root"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];

// get the resulting XML string
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

This produces the following XML string:

```
<Root>Text content for root element</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <parent>
<child name="James"> <age>10</age> <sex>male</sex>
</child> </parent>
</xml>
```

like i use this xml
write in .h file........

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
 @public
}
NSXMLParser *myXMLParser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *myXMLParser;
@end
write in .m file
- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *xmlFilePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"MyXML" ofType:@"xml"];
if ([xmlFilePath length] == 0){ /* The file could not be found in the resources folder.
}
 return;
/* Let's see if the XML file exists... */
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:xmlFilePath] == NO){
/* The XML file doesn't exist, we double checked this just to make sure we don't leave any stones unturned. You can now throw an error/exception here or do other appropriate processing */
NSLog(@"The file doesn't exist.");
 [fileManager release]; 
return;
[fileManager release];
/* Load the contents of the XML file into an NSData */ NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
self.myXMLParser = xmlParser; [xmlParser release];
[self.myXMLParser setDelegate:self];
if ([self.myXMLParser parse] == YES){
/* Successfully started to parse */ } else {
}
/* Failed to parse. Do something with this error */ 
NSError *parsingError = [self.myXMLParser parserError]; 
NSLog(@"%@", parsingError);

- (void)    parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName

namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
NSLog(@"Element Name = %@", elementName); 
NSLog(@"Number of attributes = %lu",(unsigned long)[attributeDict count]); 
if ([attributeDict count] > 0)
{
NSLog(@"Attributes dictionary = %@", attributeDict); 
NSLog(@"========================");
}
}
```