# How can I parse and update local XML in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I am trying to do following task. I know we can read XML in iOS using a parser, but can we locally update the same XML?

1) Read XML from local resource folder.
2) Update XML. Locally change value of a tag.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also be aware that the files in the resource folder get copied in the root of you app bundle and the app bundle is readonly. Thus you can't override the XML in the app bundle. You will need to save it in the document directory or if you possible in caches directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to read the XML you can use the native NSXMLParser. If you need to change the XML you can use [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML). You can get a good tutorial on how to use TouchXML [here](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/). Also interesting discussion of the various options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406811/iphone-development-xmlparser-vs-libxml2-vs-touchxml).